# Gitlab manual approval stage using a variable value

Tags: terraform, gitlab

I was trying to implement a manual approval for Terraform apply using Gitlab CI pipeline. Here am saving my script output to a variable called $CHANGES and based its value the manual approval stage has to begin. My code snippet is given below.

```
manual_approval:
  stage: manual_approval
  before_script:
  script:
    - terraform plan -input=false -out=tfplan
     - if terraform show tfplan | grep -q "No changes"; then echo "No changes"; CHANGES="false"; echo $CHANGES >> manual_approval.env; elif terraform show tfplan| grep -q "0 to change, 0 to destroy"; then echo "no destroys"; CHANGES="false"; echo $CHANGES >> manual_approval.env; else CHANGES="true"; echo $CHANGES >> manual_approval.env; fi
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: manual_approval.env  
wait_for_approval:
  stage: wait_for_approval
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "$CHANGES"
  allow_failure: false 
  rules: 
    - if: ($CHANGES == "true")
  dependencies:
    - manual_approval
terraform_apply:
  stage: terraform_apply
```

Here the I think the rule is evaluated first, hence the manual approval stage will be skipped. Is it possible to achieve this with dynamic variable or any other option in Gitlab? can somebody help me here? Thanks